# What is Pluralsight IQ and why does it show on my Developer Story?

Tags: support, developer-story, pluralsight-iq

I use Developer Story to track my score (yeah vanity) just to spot this:

[image: PluralsightIQ "How do your dev skills stack up"]

Is it an advertisement, or is Stack Overflow affiliated with Pluralsight now?

Comment: Nope, this isn't an ad. We've partnered with Pluralsight to integrate Pluralsight IQ, their skills assessment product. We'll publish a post shortly with more detail!

Comment: @Des there is no Test for SQL Server IQ level, how can we suggest it? we have to do this in meta or we have to contact PLURALSIGHT?

Comment: @Hadi you can make suggestions here on meta and we'll make sure Pluralsight gets them. Noted this one :)

Comment: @Des: it also appears broken for me. No adblockers, no userscripts, just Firefox 58 on OS X High Sierra. No console errors, but clicking on the link just produces a sad little scroll (an empty `#` hash target is added to the URL).

Comment: @Des i posted a request here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362731/no-sql-server-iq-test-on-pluralsight-iq-test

Comment: @MartijnPieters checking it out

Comment: @g3rv4: ah, I misunderstood what happens. The scroll takes me to the 'new item' box, which updates to switch to the *assessment* item to be added. I only realised this after seeing the blog posting. Perhaps the transition needs to be jazzed up a little, with a NUX box saying something about *add your assessment to your timeline here* or something?

Comment: @MartijnPieters after the scroll, you're supposed to [see this prompt](https://gmc.uy/assessmentPrompt.png) and then click on the "Get your Skill IQ" button

Comment: @Hadi thanks! I've passed it along to the Pluralsight team. I'll update the post with any feedback I get.

Comment: @g3rv4: I do see that, but it wasn't clear to me what was supposed to happen. All I noticed was the scroll, not the 'add' box transitioning. I haven't touched my developer story in eons, so unfamiliarity with the way the page works played a role too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters excellent, your feedback is super useful :) I just wanted to rule out a technical bug.

Comment: It is not showing my proficiency when I add it to my story, my developer story now looks like it just contains an ad for Pluralsight.

Comment: Anyone else finding that the Pluralsight IQ tests lock-up and need the page to be refreshed? Happens several times during each test for me. I've been timed out on more than one question because the page locked up and by the time I got it responding again the timer had reached zero.